# I write a MySQL table into an output file (working on Unix) but I can not enter the file directory (permission denied)

Tags: mysql, file, directory

When I output a whole table into an output file named 'Arshan.txt' this command works well but I can not access the output file created. When I access /usr/local/mysql/data it says permission denied. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to access the file using the same account the MySQL process is running under. If you're an administrator on the machine you can also use `sudo` to execute any command with superuser privileges. For example:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/data/Arshan.txt ~foo/Arshan.txt
sudo chown foo ~foo/Arshan.txt
```

Comment: When I enter this command it says no such file or directory. thats strange. I used the following mysql statement

Comment: SELECT * From CLA INTO OUTFILE 'Arshan.txt'

Comment: If it says the file doesn't exist even when using `sudo`, the file definitely doesn't exist. Perhaps you saved it in a different path than you think you did, or perhaps the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` query didn't work.

Comment: Thats what I thought too but when I repeat the above statement in MySQL it says 'Arshan.txt' already exists :(

Comment: In that case it's a question of the path you're using. Changing the path to something outside of `/usr/local/mysql/` is wise anyway. Why risk mixing up generated output with proper database files.

Comment: thank you so much for your replies. I tried changing the path too but it says 'Cant create/write to file.

Comment: Then make sure MySQL's account can write wherever you're trying to have it write.

Comment: The "SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE" statement saves it into the specific directory of the selected database, not the top-level directory. So it's not "/usr/local/mysql/data/Arshan.txt". It's "/usr/local/mysql/data/your_database_name/Arshan.txt". Besides the slight difference in paths, VoteyDisciple's commands should work.

Comment: Although, I would opt for a "sudo mv ..." instead of a "sudo cp ..." to avoid leaving stale files around.